# $1$-dimensional representations of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Tags: representation-theory

I have some questions about $1$-dimensional representations of $G=\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$. I need to show that there are $q-1$  $1$-dimensional representations of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$. I am able to show that $[G,G] = \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$. It follows that $f: G/[G,G] \cong \mathbb{F}_q^*$ given by $f(g) = \det(g)$ is an isomorphism. Therefore for each homomorphism $\xi: \mathbb{F}_q^* \to \mathbb{C}^*$, we have a homomorphism $G \to \mathbb{C}^*$ given by $G \to G/[G,G] \to \mathbb{F}_q^* \to \mathbb{C}^*$. My question is

(1) How could we know that every homomorphism $G \to \mathbb{C}^*$ is given in this way?

(2) How to show that there are $q-1$ $1$-dimensional representations of $G=\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The $1$-dimensional (complex) representations are in bijection with the irreducible representations of the abelianization of the group. And the irreducible representations of a finite abelian group are isomorphic to the group itself.

Comment: Tobias summed it up pretty well. Just feeling the need to remark that you need to be careful with $q=2$. In that case $SL_2=GL_2$, and the commutator subgroup is strictly smaller. As any permutation of the three non-zero elements of $\Bbb{F}_2^2$ is linear, we have that $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_2)\simeq S_3$. You probably know that this group has two non-isomorphic 1-dimensional representations, so the claim does not hold in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{C}^*$ is an abelian group, it follows that $[G,G] \leq \operatorname{Ker}(\theta)$ for any homomorphism $\theta: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$. Thus $\theta$ induces a well defined homomorphism $\hat{\theta}: G / [G,G] \rightarrow \mathbb{C^*}$ by $x[G,G] \mapsto \theta(x)$.

You can check that $\theta \mapsto \hat{\theta}$ defines a bijection between one-dimensional representations of $G$ and $G/[G,G]$. Injectivity is easy, and surjectivity follows from what you have done in your question.

For any finite abelian group $A$, it is possible to prove that the number of one-dimensional representations of $A$ is equal to the order of $A$. Hence for a finite group $G$, the number of one-dimensional representations of $G$ is equal to the order of $G/[G,G]$.

As Jyrki noted in the comments, you should note that $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ has $q-1$ one-dimensional representations only when $q$ is odd. The problem with the $q = 2$ case is that then $[G,G]$ is not $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$.